# How to configure hd memory in hazel cast 5.3.6 enterprise version

Tags: java, hazelcast

please explain the parameters of hd memory which we configure when we use in-memory type as NATIVE in hazelcast`

(https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.3/storage/high-density-memory#configuring-high-density-memory-store)
but not able to understand the relevance of these parameters, like what is numa node and is there a need to use mounted if we have server for each node for hazelcast

thanks for helping :)